# RoR + Sidekiq background processes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to get my list to go closed when the End Date is met.
Could anyone help me? I'm using sidekiq for background processes and I already have my list passing closed status, but not when it reaches the end date.

My table

```
create_table "lists", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer "user_id"
t.binary "uuid", limit: 36
t.string "name"
t.string "description"
t.datetime "end_date"
t.integer "status", default: 1
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_lists_on__user_id"
```

I did this in the sidekiq so that my list goes to the disabled state

```
    class HardJob
    include Sidekiq::Job

    def perform(list_id)
     list = List.find list_id
     list.disabled!

     return 0
    end
   end
```

Comment: How do you schedule the job in question?

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule a job with a cronjob that runs every day at a specific time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).